# is it possible to achieve Windows XP-like taskbar under Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-10, taskbar, desktop

I have not liked what has become of the taskbar since Windows XP (or for that matter, the Ribbon interface of Microsoft Office software, which for me is the opposite of intuitive). Under XP, the taskbar icons were considerably smaller and didn't take up as much screen real-estate as they do in Windows 7, and more of them would fit vertically too.  I know that Microsoft is moving towards the "bigger is better" in the UI, to try to bridge the divide between desktop and touch. That requires a sort of hierarchical taskbar interface. But I'm wondering if they've since implemented a "classic XP look" option, since there were quite a few complaints about the new UI from long-time XP users.

Comment: There's a small buttons option that would allow around 40 icons on my 14in 1600x900 laptop.

Comment: You should get most of what you want from [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/). In particular, I don't know of another way to get back the traditional **Programs** extending menu of installed programs: many of the entries are missing from from the Win10 **All apps** menu.

Comment: http://www.intowindows.com/windows-xp-themes-for-windows-10/

Comment: Windows 10 (and many ultra-modern websites) are aiming for higher and higher resolution screens. Some laptops are boasting 2560x1440 or higher resolution which means buttons have to scale dynamically or be big (and ugly in my opinion). Not directly related to the question, but hopefully useful background info. Unfortunately the only way to get the true XP look is to do something like run XP as a VM (virtual machine) which is what I do...and I spend more time on XP than in Windows 10!